# Wordpress php issue with creating custom filter

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, filter

I'm new to working with filters, but am keen to make my plugin that I am building extensible.

In my main plugin I have the following class and function:

```
class Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages {

// Return (array) the properties of all Skizzar Admin Theme admin pages
static function get_pages( $page_slug = '' ) {

    $pages = array();
    // Default page properties
    $default_args = array(
        'menu-title' => '',
        'tab-title' => '',
        'parent' => 'admin.php',
        'in-menu' => false,
        'has-tab' => true,
        'tab-side' => false,
        'top-level' => false,
    );

    $pages['sat-options-general'] = array_merge(
        $default_args,
        array(
            'slug' => 'sat-options-general',
            'menu-title' => _x( 'Admin Theme', 'Page title in the menu', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'tab-title' => _x( 'Admin Theme Options', 'Option tab title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'title' => _x( 'Admin Theme Options', 'Option page title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'callback' => array( __CLASS__, 'display_general_options_page' ),
            'in-menu' => true,
            'top-level' => true,
        )
    );

    $pages['sat-addons'] = array_merge(
        $default_args,
        array(
            'slug' => 'sat-addons',
            'menu-title' => _x( 'Addons', 'Page title in the menu', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'tab-title' => _x( 'Addons', 'Option tab title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'title' => _x( 'Browse Addons', 'Option page title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'callback' => array( __CLASS__, 'display_addons_page' ),
            'in-menu' => true,
        )
    );



    return apply_filters( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', $pages, $default_args, $page_slug ); 

}

// Output the content of the requested options page
static function display_general_options_page() {
    $page_info = self::get_pages( 'sat-options-general' );
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/page-options-general.php' );
}
...
}
```

In a nutshell, this array is used to create a submenu page and tabs across the top of that page, amongst other things. You will see I have added the filter:

```
apply_filters( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', $pages, $default_args, $page_slug );
```

To the function `get_pages()`, this is so I can add pages from an addon plugin.

In my addon plugin, I have the following function:

```
function add_google_analytics_tab( $pages, $default_args, $page_slug ) {

    $pages['sat-ga'] = array_merge(
            $default_args,
            array(
                'slug' => 'sat-ga',
                'menu-title' => _x( 'GA', 'Page title in the menu', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
                'tab-title' => _x( 'GA', 'Option tab title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
                'title' => _x( 'GA', 'Option page title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
                'callback' => array( __CLASS__, 'display_ga_page' ),
                'in-menu' => true,
            )
        );
        // Return
        if ( $page_slug ) {
            if ( ! isset( $pages[ $page_slug ] ) ) {
                return null;
            }
            return $pages[ $page_slug ];
        }
        return $pages;
}
function display_ga_page() {
    echo 'GA Settings Go Here';
}
```

This is then called using the following add_filter function:

```
add_filter( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', array(&$this, 'add_google_analytics_tab', 1, 3) );
```

The hope is that this will add the array to the `get_pages()` function in my main plugin, thus adding the submenu item and tabs etc.

However, I am met with the fololwing errors:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in ...plugin.php on line 235

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...class-sat-menu.php on line 13
```

Here is the referenced line in class-sat-menu.php

```
static function action_add_menu_entries() {

    // Skizzar Admin Theme pages
    foreach ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages::get_pages() as $page_info ) {

        if ( ! $page_info['in-menu'] ) {
            $page_info['parent'] = null;
        }

        if ($page_info['top-level']) {
            add_menu_page(
                $page_info['title'], // Page Title
                ( $page_info['menu-title'] ? $page_info['menu-title'] : $page_info['title'] ), // Menu Title
                Skizzar_Admin_Theme_User::get_admin_cap(), // Capability
                $page_info['slug'], // Slug
                $page_info['callback'] // Callback
            );

        }
        else {
            add_submenu_page(
                'sat-options-general',
                $page_info['title'],
                ( $page_info['menu-title'] ? $page_info['menu-title'] : $page_info['title'] ),
                Skizzar_Admin_Theme_User::get_admin_cap(),
                $page_info['slug'],
                $page_info['callback']
            );
        }

    }

}
```

I can't quite get my head around what the error is, so any advise or help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you print and see `Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages::get_pages()` what this is returning? Generally these errors would come if the element is not iterable.

Comment: OK, so I did print Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages::get_pages(); within the function display_general_options_page() and it just shows "array"

Comment: I just used print - print_r and var_dump break the site (syntax error, unexpected 'Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages')

Comment: I think `Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Pages::get_pages()` is not giving you an iterable object. Take the ouput to a variable and then `var_dump` and see what it is returning